# Cant find 7Zip after installation Mythbuntu

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I installed 7Zip through web but cant find it in the menue nor anywhere else.
What goes wrong?

Greets 
Tom

Comment: How did you install?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to also install *xarchiver*:

`sudo apt-get install p7zip xarchiver`

Then run *xarchiver* (should be in the Accessories menu) and 7zip will be a format available.